# Why are my props `undefined` when using redux and react Native?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I followed all the steps to create a store, but I when I try to access my props, they are undefined. I am using react Native , redux, and the connect component from 'react-redux'. Please help . I cant move forward.

this is where I connect props to state :

```
const  mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    location : state.location
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MapsScreen);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignContent:'center',
    }
})
```

This is the component :

```
import LocationComp from './location'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../../redux/actions'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
export class MapsScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
            isLoading : true
        }
    handleLanguage = (loco) => {
        store.dispatch(actions.newLocation(loco))
        this.setState({ isLoading: !this.state.isLoading })
        console.log(store.getState())
    }
    render() {
    return (
    <View style = {{flex :1}}>
        {this.state.isLoading === true ?
        (
            <LocationComp getLocation = {this.handleLanguage}/> 
        ):(

            <MapView
                style={{flex:1}}
                initialRegion={{
                latitude: 37.78825,
                longitude: -122.4324,
                latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}>
                {console.log(this.props.location)}
                </MapView>
        )}    
        </View> 
    );
    }
```

}

My store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducer'
import {addTest} from './actions'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

export default store =  createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

My reducer  :

```
import {UPDATE_TEST,  UPDATE_LOCATION,} from './actions'
import { combineReducers} from 'redux'

const merge = (prev, next ) => Object.assign({}, prev, next) 
const hustleReducer = (state = [], action) =>  {
    if(action.type === UPDATE_TEST) {
        return   [...state, action.payload]
    }
    return state
}
const locoReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
    if(action.type === UPDATE_LOCATION){
        return merge(state.location, action.payload)
    }
    return state
}
export default reducer = combineReducers({
    hustleList : hustleReducer,
    location : locoReducer,
})
```

my actions :

```
/// action creators 
export const UPDATE_TEST= 'UPDATE_TEST'
export const UPDATE_LOCATION = 'UPDATE_LOCATION'

export const addTest = newContact => ({
    type : UPDATE_TEST,
    payload : newContact

})
export const newLocation = newLocation =>({
    type : UPDATE_LOCATION,
    payload : newLocation
})
```

Comment: Please paste some part of the code

Comment: Why this line `
const merge = (prev, next ) => Object.assign({}, prev, next`

Answer (score 0):

You dont need merge, try return something like `return {{...state.location}, {...action.payload}}`

Comment: I was following a tutorial. I will try that . Would that make my props undefined